# How to replace the content of a dict in Python using regex

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have to modify a very large JSON file (36MB), basically what I need is to delete the timestamps of the entire file.

Since I cannot use sublime text or another IDE since the application crashes, I have no choice but to process the file manually using python.

The process I had in mind was the following:

1. Open JSON file
2. Convert JSON file to dict
3. Delete timestamps in the dict
4. Export the dict in json format in a new file.

Here is my question:

I need to edit the entire dict and replace TXX:XX:XX with ‘ ‘ (empty character). The JSON file must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.

So let's say I have this date: `2021-11-02T00:04:03` after replacing the timestamp it should be like: `2021-11-02`

One more example:

`2021-10-02T01:04:03` should be `2021-10-02`

And so on.

I know this regex `T00.{6}` would work for case 00, but what about the other cases? 01, 02, 03, 04 ... etc. Is there a generic regex for all cases?

And most importantly, how can I look up all values in a dictionary and replace timestamps with `""`.

Comment: "I cannot use sublime text ... since the application crashes" warrants more attention. This seems unlikely, in my experience. Perhaps you have an errant plug-in, so try with all plugins disabled.

Comment: No, I tried on different computers and different apps such as Visual Studio Code, just the file is too large to perform a `Find - Replace All`

Comment: Do you know which fields contain timestamps?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the problem is:

1. Determine if a given string is of the form `####-##-##T##:##:##`, where # is any digit;
2. If so, truncate the string to only contain the part before the T; if not, leave the string as-is.

If this is correct, we can do:

```
def truncate_timestamp(potential_date_str):
  pattern = '^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$'
  match = re.search(pattern, potential_date_str)
  if match:
    return match.group(1)
  else:
    return potential_date_str
```

This produces the following results:

```
>>> truncate_timestamp('2021-11-02T00:04:03')
'2021-11-02'
>>> truncate_timestamp('Canned Frozen Orange Juice')
'Canned Frozen Orange Juice'
```

`re.search` returns something truthy if it successfully matched, and otherwise returns something falsy.  The pattern given in `pattern` here just transparently encodes the fact that the string consists of four digits, followed by a dash, etc., and has a capture group for the date part.  If we successfully match, we return what we captured, which will be the date.  If not, this wasn't a timestamp, so we leave it alone.

Comment: Good point! Now what I need is to go through all the values of that dictionary (there may be several nodes/levels), and check for pattern matches. Any ideas?

Comment: @Cheknov: Either breadth-first search or depth-first search.